# Porting a Linux C Project to Windows with Mingw: Issues with 'move' Command in Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, mingw, mingw32

I'm currently in the process of porting a C project that I originally developed on Linux to a Windows environment using Mingw. I've successfully compiled and run the project on Linux after making some necessary code changes. To test its compatibility on Windows, I used Wine and ran it on an actual Windows machine, where it worked flawlessly.

Now, my goal is to compile the project directly on a Windows machine. I've installed Mingw on the Windows system, and I'm attempting to use the `mingw32-make` command. The compiler is being called successfully, and I've managed to create folders exchanging the following rule

```
$(RELEASE_ODIRS) $(RELEASE_DDIRS):
    mkdir -p $@
```

by the this new cross-platform rule:

```
$(RELEASE_ODIRS) $(RELEASE_DDIRS):
ifeq ($(PLATFORM), Windows)
    if not exist $(subst /,\,$@) mkdir $(subst /,\,$@)
else
    mkdir -p $@
endif
```

Hovewer, I've encountered an issue when trying to replace the `mv -f` command in my Makefile with `move`. Specifically, the make process fails with the following error:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, move release\.deps\input_stream.Td release\.deps\input_stream.d, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Interestingly, if I run the move command directly in the Windows Command Prompt (cmd), it works without any issues. My question is twofold: Why can't Make find the move utility, while it can locate mkdir successfully? Additionally, I'd appreciate any tips or insights on how to streamline the porting process without creating a separate build script specifically for Windows. My aim is to use the same Makefile for both environments.

Comment: There is neither `mv` nor `move` in the snippets posted. What is the point of posting unrelated code omitting the problematic one?

Comment: I also want a review on what I've done so far. Why criticize if you have nothing to help me with? You're wasting both my time and yours posting a comment like this...

Comment: I do have. But for that I need to see the problematic code as anyone here. The general rule is to have a [mcve] in a question. Even with your unfriendly reply I will try to guess. `mv` is a valid `bash` command recognized in `mingw` environment, unlike `move`  which is `cmd.exe` command. So it is unclear why you are trying to replace it.

Comment: The point of criticizing your question is to motivate you to improve it. Improvements to address the criticism raised would be to everyone's advantage, including yours.  If anything is time-wasting, it is posting questions that do not meet [our standards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and therefore are difficult for us to answer satisfactorily.

Comment: Put another way you wrote your question one time, but (so far) over 20 people have read and tried to understand the question.  Why is your time (not taking time to write a complete and comprehensible question) more valuable than the time of the 20+ other people who try to figure out how to help?

Comment: But anyway, the problem is obvious from the error.  `move` is a built-in command in the Windows cmd.exe shell.  If make is invoking `cmd.exe` as its shell, then the `move` command will work.  If make is invoking some other shell (for example, the POSIX shell) then `move` will not be found and you'll get the error you see above.  Although the problem is obvious, since you didn't show us the rule in question that generated the error, we can't give you any suggestions on how to fix it.

Comment: As you want to use `mingw32-make` I suggest to use a MinGW or MSys environment, i.e. a shell with UNIX-like commands. Then you probably don't need to modify the Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

If I open a Command Prompt and type `where move` to tell me where `move.exe` is located in the `PATH` it can't find it.

But if I run `move /?` I do get the help.

So it looks like it's a built-in command, not an external application, so you can't call it from `Makefile`, unless you use it from the shell with something like `CMD /C move`.

**Solution**

When porting to Windows using tools like autoconf and make it's a lot easier to use [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) shell, which provides a bash shell for native Windows allowing you to use your unmodified build files (like `Makefile` or even `./configure`).

**Alternative**

An alternative solution could be to move away from make and use another cross-platform build system. A good candidate is [CMake](https://cmake.org/) in combination with [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/), which both work well on Windows.